# Failed to deploy application to heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am newbie into heroku. I was trying to deploy a Django application to heroku by following steps.

1. Installed vartualenv
2. Installed Django gunicron via pip
3. Installed heroku toolbelt
4. Created an empty git
5. git add .
6. git commit -m "First commit"
7. ssh-keygen
8. heroku create
9. heroku keys:add
10. git push heroku master

And the a error

```
(venv)han@HEEL:~/Desktop/projects/ossko$ heroku keys:add
Found existing public key: /home/han/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key /home/han/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
(venv)han@HEEL:~/Desktop/projects/ossko$ git push heroku master
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have follow every steps from heroku help site.

Please help me to fix this error

I have Ubuntu 13.4 64bit os

**Update:** here is the result of `git remote -v`:

> $git remote -v
>   heroku git@heroku.com:infinite-mesa-xxx.git (fetch)
>   heroku git@heroku.com:infinite-mesa-xxx.git (push)

Comment: Are you perhaps behind a firewall that's blocking port 22?

Comment: I dont know, How to check that?
Well i can push trough github...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i just solved the problem, This problem is with adding ssh key.
So the correct commands for heroku deploying is

```
nihan@heel:~$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: debashis.dip@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden): 
Authentication successful.
nihan@heel:~$ cd dev/flask-app
nihan@heel:~/dev/flask-app$ heroku keys:clear
Removing all SSH keys... done
nihan@heel:~/dev/flask-app$ heroku keys:add
Found existing public key: /home/nihan/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key /home/nihan/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
nihan@heel:~/dev/flask-app$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa   <---- This was the missing key
Enter passphrase for /home/nihan/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/nihan/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/nihan/.ssh/id_rsa)
nihan@heel:~/dev/flask-app$ git push heroku master
```

Because my ssh never knew which key to use it somehow have heroku the wrong information and that's why heroku was denying.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `git remote -v`. Does it give you more than one remote, like this?

> your_app_name        git@heroku.com:your_app_name.git (fetch)
>   your_app_name        git@heroku.com:your_app_name.git (push)

If the remote depot is named something other than 'heroku' you will need to specify the push to that site instead. For example, if your remote is named `ossko`, try something like

> git push ossko master

Often you will have different names for remote depots if you have more than one heroku app - you can use a different name for each app.

Comment: (venv)han@HEEL:~/Desktop/projects/ossko$ git remote -v
heroku git@heroku.com:infinite-mesa-xxx.git (fetch)
heroku git@heroku.com:infinite-mesa-xxx.git (push)

Here is the result of git remote -v